# Retrieving data in unidimensional array in Cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-1.3

I am using cakephp 1.3 to extract data from a table with **Cities** and **Postal Codes** and I would like to extract these two columns to populate drop down menu with postal codes as **menu 'id'** and **town names** as menu **'values'**.

The “*find( 'list')*” method is out of option because some of the towns have the same postcodes and the class is picking only unique value so instead of getting :

```
Array
(
    [800] =>  Darwin
    [801] =>  Darwin
    [810] =>  Allawa    
)
```

I am getting

```
Array
(
    [800] =>  Darwin
    [810] =>  Allawa    
)
```

The method find('all') is returning a multidimensional array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [GeoPostcode] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => 26
                    [region] => Acton
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [GeoPostcode] => Array
                (
                    [state_id] => 26
                    [region] => Ainslie
                )
        )
)
```

What is the best work around to get the desired data in unidimensional array without reducing the output to unique array keys? Something like :

```
Array ( [800] => Darwin [801] => Darwin [810] => Allawa )
```

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: Look at the first block, there you see the expected output.

Comment: @aldrin27 the expected output is Array
(
    [800] =>  Darwin
    [801] =>  Darwin
    [810] =>  Allawa    
)

Comment: Do you have a table that stores the postal codes? Or are they stored in the same table as City Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should still be able to do this with `$Model->find('list')`.

```
$this->Model->find(
    'list',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'postal_code',
            'city_name'
        ),
        'contain' => false
    )
);
```

This should return a list resultset using the two fields that you selected (postal code and city name).

Your alternate option, is to do a `find('all')`:

```
$results = $this->Model->find(
               'all',
               array(
                   'conditions' => array( ... )
               )
           );
```

Now, you have this format in your data results:

```
$results = Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [ModelName] => Array
              (
                  [id] => 1
                  [postal_code] => 800,
                  [city_name] => 'Darwin'
              )

      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [ModelName] => Array
              (
                  [id] => 2
                  [postal_code] => 801,
                  [city_name] => 'Darwin'
              )
      )

  [2] => Array
      (
          [ModelName] => Array
              (
                  [id] => 3
                  [postal_code] => 810,
                  [city_name] => 'Allawa'
              )
      )
)
```

Then use the `Set` class within Cake to extract some data:

```
 $keys   = Set::extract('/ModelName/postal_code', $results);
 $values = Set::extract('/ModelName/city_name', $results);


 /* Then some array_combine magic */
 $list   = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Now you have an array that is what you want. Albeit a longer way, but it works. You can then pass this variable to your `Form::select()` helper to create your dropdown.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1. The result find('list') doesn't work if you have two identical key.
2. The same when it comes to Set class within the Cakephp. In your demo your are using different postal_code for both 'Darwin' elements. If you set the same postal code for both 'Darwin' elements you will get back an array with one missing element: 

Array
(
    [800] => Darwin
    [802] => Allawa
)
The issue is narrowing down to php array_combine($keys, $values); method which is apparently designed to ignore key duplicates.

Comment: Why would you have two identical keys?

Comment: I used the same example you did. Where you used 800 and 801 for darwin